# Issue with restoring data after device was rotated

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation

I checked a lot of other answers on the similar question as mine, but still cannot understand what is wrong there.

I have activity and fragment

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:background="#CCC"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout fragmentContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("LOG", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            openFragment();
        } else {
            replaceFragment();
        }
    }

    private void openFragment() {
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setId(12345);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(),
            new SimpleFragment(), "SimpleFragment").commit();

        fragmentContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        fragmentContainer.addView(ll);
    }

    private void replaceFragment() {
        final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.setId(12345);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(ll.getId(),
            new SimpleFragment(), "SimpleFragment").commit();

        fragmentContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        fragmentContainer.addView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("LOG", "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

And simple fragment

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Simple Fragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class SimpleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String aaa = savedInstanceState.getString("AAA");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), aaa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.d("LOG", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("LOG", "fragment onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("LOG", "fragment onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("AAA", "Hello");
    }

}
```

So what's the problem:

When I rotate device app should save a state and then restore it (lets assume some variables).

Right after rotation **onSaveInstanceState** is executed. 
Data is saved. 
Then fragment's **onCreate** is executed and data is restored.

Thats OK. And it's expected behaviour.

But then because of activity is recreated as well, fragment should be added (replaced) again. As result fragment's **onCreate** is executed again. And I see fragment without saved data. I see newly created fragment.

How to avoid this creation?

I rotate device, data is saved and then restored. fragment is visible on activity with restored data.

So what is algorithm of adding fragment to the activity, in order not to add it after rotation and avoid recreation?

Comment: both of your methods are doing same thing, because you are creating new linear layout and inflat fragment in that layout and add it in fragment_contianer

Comment: ok, I see. But what is the correct way of adding fragments and the save it's state? Some king of static fragments? Or save fragment's state in activity? I cannot find correct solution? Is it possible in Android? )

Comment: only getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
            new SimpleFragment(), "SimpleFragment").commit(); will add the fragment in R.id.fragment_container and .same line of code with .replace will replace the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add from layout

In general you don't need to add additional container for your fragment from code. The simplest way of adding fragment is define `<fragment .../>` in your layout with **`android:id`** property!!!

Example for your case:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("LOG", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("LOG", "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

and **main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#CCC"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="your.package.name.SimpleFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment code and layout are not require any changes.

### Add from code

If you really need to add it from code you don't need to add additional container from code. Just add fragment if it is first launch - after system will do it for you.

Example for your case:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("LOG", "onCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            openFragment();
        }
    }

    private void openFragment() {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
                new SimpleFragment(), "SimpleFragment").commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("LOG", "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

and **main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:background="#CCC"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment code and layout are not require any changes.

Comment: thanks for reply & sorry for delay ) but instead of static path, like your.package.name.SimpleFragment I have to add it programmatically. I have a menu and when I click on item, appropriate fragment should be opened. So looks like I have to find how to do the same (<fragment ... SimpleFragment) but adding in the code. At this moment I cannot achieve this ((